# Problem loading images on Cultofmac.com in Safari and Chrome

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome, web-browsing

I have had a problem with the [cultofmac](http://www.cultofmac.com) site for a little while now.

The pages will load the text, video and some ads. But does not load the main images for the articles until about a minute. This is per page load.

I did at one point have a beta Safari 6.1 running when I first had the problem start. But only after a couple of weeks of using the beta.

I have switched back to Safari 6.0.5 and still have the same problem.
Checking the site in Chrome gives me the same problem. But takes even longer to load if at all.

This does seem to me to be a problem at cultofmac's end with badly constructed javascript and cross domain irregularities.

(All other sites are fine.)

Looking at the Console Log (Safari): which stay blank for the first minute.
Then exactly as the page images start to load I get. errors like these:

---

From Safari

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://www.cultofmac.com/ from frame with URL
>   http://rs.gwallet.com/r1/axbanner?winprice=UkG3IgAE7WQKwo3kAABZub0c2HP1BDKsTDxKew&clickurl=http://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/aclk....kcbkkng41.
>   Domains, protocols and ports must match.

(Above http middle content is trimmed. It was very very long)

> Failed to load resource: The request timed out. 
>   https://app-stacksocial.netdna-ssl.com/assets/dealOfTheDay.js

and

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://www.cultofmac.com/ from frame with URL
>   http://bsa.adsrv.us/1278819/backfill5.html. Domains, protocols and
>   ports must match.

---

From Chrome:

> Blocked a frame with origin "http://w.coin.scribol.com" from accessing
>   a frame with origin "http://www.cultofmac.com". Protocols, domains,
>   and ports must match. ScribolTemplate.min.js:1
>   ScribolTemplate.parseUrlScribolTemplate.min.js:1
>   ScribolTemplate.trackImpressionsScribolTemplate.min.js:1 (anonymous
>   function)5?hpage=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cultofmac.com%2F247370%2Fios-7-mail-now-lets-you-view-files-inside-zipped-attachments%2F:111
>   njquery.min.js:2 o.fireWithjquery.min.js:2
>   e.extend.readyjquery.min.js:2 c.addEventListener.Bjquery.min.js:

I have tried to contact their web support with no response.

1, can anyone confirm if they are also getting this issue with the site.

2, Is there any fix anyone can think of my end. 
(Blocking the ads does not work. It just makes the matter worse by stopping the whole site loading)

Details.

- iMac 27" 2011.
- Safari - Version 6.0.5 (8536.30.1)
- Chrome - Version 29.0.1547.76

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone at work Suggested I change my DNS servers to openDNS and see if that resolves the problem.

As it may be that the DNS server from my provider is what is slowing down the page load due to the cross domain calls.

I just tried googles 8.8.8.8 and  8.8.4.4  DNS servers.

It turns out that this is indeed the case.
The images load as one would expect. And changing back to the IP's DNS the Problem reoccurs.

But I do not really want to change my DNS servers. So will be asking a separate question related to this.

Answer (score 0):

Cross domain errors seem to be common with sites that server google ads, retry with chrome and get an adblock extension. most likely the main images are waiting for everything else to load.

Comment: Thanks sean,I have ad blocking in a virus checker which I can use but I said ad blocking seems to make this site not load ever.